# PNG file that says JPEG(Document) in Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I recived a layerd PNG file from my designer. The problem is that the file even though it is a PNG says JPEG(Document) in the left corner of the preview window in Fireworks. B/c of that I cannot save my slices as PNG's. Do yo know how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution,

In the upper right corner of Fireworks there is a tab "Optimize". If your window says "JPEG(Document)" then you will see JPEG, so just change it to PNG.

Simple but was hard to find.

Thanks to Arek for finding this out.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the file really is a JPEG which Fireworks finds out by inspecting the contents, and your designer just saved it with the `.png` suffix?

Comment: But it contains all the layers,

Comment: Hmm, to my knowledge PNG does not even support layers. Neither JPEGs do. I think I'm out here. :-)

Comment: Yes it does. :-) Found the answer and posted it.

Comment: Neither PNG nor JPEG support layers.